# How do I safely read a variable from one thread and modify it from another?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a class instances which is being used in multiple threads. I am updating multiple member variables from one thread and reading the same member variables from one thread. What is the correct way to maintain the thread safety?

```
eg:
  phthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1)
    obj1.memberV1 = 1;
  //unlock here?
```

Should I unlock the mutex over here? ( if another thread access the obj1 member variables 1 and 2 now, the accessed data might not be correct because memberV2 has not yet be updated. However, if I does not release the lock, the other thread might block because there is time consuming operation below.

```
 //perform some time consuming operation which must be done before the assignment to memberV2 and after the assignment to memberV1
    obj1.memberV2 = update field 2 from some calculation
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1) //should I only unlock here?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your locking is correct.  You should *not* release the lock early just to allow another thread to proceed (because that would allow the other thread to see the object in an inconsistent state.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better to do something like:

```
//perform time consuming calculation
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1)
  obj1.memberV1 = 1;
  obj1.memberV2 = result;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1)
```

This of course assumes that the values used in the calculation won't be *modified* on any other thread.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what you are doing that is causing problems.  The mutex pattern is pretty simple.  You Lock the mutex, access the shared data, unlock the mutex.  This protects data, becuase the mutex will only let one thread get the lock at a time.  Any thread that fails to get the lock has to wait till the mutex is unlocked.  Unlocking wakes the waiters up.  They will then fight to attain the lock.  Losers go back to sleep.  The time it takes to wake up might be multiple ms or more from the time the lock is released.  Make sure you always unlock the mutex eventually.

Make sure you don't to keep locks locked for a long period of time.  Most of the time, a long period of time is like a micro second. I prefer to keep it down around "a few lines of code."  Thats why people have suggested that you do the long running calculation outside the lock.  The reason for not keeping locks a long time is you increase the number of times other threads will hit the lock and have to spin or sleep, which decreases performance.  You also increase the probability that your thread might be pre-empted while owning the lock, which means the lock is enabled while that thread sleeps.  Thats even worse performance.

Threads that fail a lock dont have to sleep.  Spinning means a thread encountering a locked mutex doesn't sleep, but loops repeatedly testing the lock for a predefine period before giving up and sleeping.  This is a good idea if you have multiple cores or cores capable of multiple simultaneous threads.   Multiple active threads means two threads can be executing the code at the same time.  If the lock is around a small amount of code, then the thread that got the lock is going to be done real soon.  the other thread need only wait a couple nano secs before it will get the lock.  Remember, sleeping your thread is a context switch and some code to attach your thread to the waiters on the mutex, all have costs.  Plus, once your thread sleeps, you have to wait for a period of time before the scheduler wakes it up.  that could be multiple ms.  Lookup spinlocks.

If you only have one core, then if a thread encounters a lock it means another sleeping thread owns the lock and no matter how long you spin it aint gonna unlock.  So you would use a lock that sleeps a waiter immediately in hopes that the thread owning the lock will wake up and finish.

You should assume that a thread can be preempted at any machine code instruction.  Also you should assume that each line of c code is probably many machine code instructions.  The classic example is i++.  This is one statement in c, but a read, an increment, and a store in machine code land.

If you really care about performance, try to use atomic operations first.  Look to mutexes as a last resort.  Most concurrency problems are easily solved with atomic operations (google gcc atomic operations to start learning) and very few problems really need mutexes.  Mutexes are way way way slower.

Protect your shared data wherever it is **written** and wherever it is **read**.  else...prepare for failure.  You don't have to protect shared data during periods of time when only a single thread is active.

Its often useful to be able to run your app with 1 thread as well as N threads.  This way you can debug race conditions easier.

Minimize the shared data that you protect with locks.  Try to organize data into structures such that a single thread can gain exclusive access to the entire structure (perhaps by setting a single locked flag or version number or both) and not have to worry about anything after that.  Then most of the code isnt cluttered with locks and race conditions.

Functions that ultimately write to shared variables should use temp variables until the last moment and then copy the results.  Not only will the compiler generate better code, but accesses to shared variables especially changing them cause cache line updates between L2 and main ram and all sorts of other performance issues.  Again if you don't care about performance disregard this.  However i recommend you google the document "everything a programmer should know about memory" if you want to know more.

If you are reading a single variable from the shared data you probably don't need to lock as long as the variable is an integer type and not a member of a bitfield (bitfield members are read/written with multiple instructions).  Read up on atomic operations.  When you need to deal with multiple values, then you need a lock to make sure you didn't read version A of one value, get preempted,  and then read version B of the next value.  Same holds true for writing.

You will find that copies of data, even copies of entire structures come in handy.  You can be working on building a new copy of the data and then swap it by changing a pointer in with one atomic operation.  You can make a copy of the data and then do calculations on it without worrying if it changes.

So maybe what you want to do is:

```
lock the mutex
  Make a copy of the input data to the long running calculation.
unlock the mutex

L1: Do the calculation

Lock the mutex
   if the input data has changed and this matters
     read the input data, unlock the mutex and go to L1
   updata data
unlock mutex
```

Maybe, in the example above, you still store the result if the input changed, but go back and recalc.  It depends if other threads can use a slightly out of date answer.  Maybe other threads when they see that a thread is already doing the calculation simply change the input data and leave it to the busy thread to notice that and redo the calculation (there will be a race condition you need to handle if you do that, and easy one).  That way the other threads can do other work rather than just sleep.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do is:

```
temp = //perform some time consuming operation which must be done before the assignment to memberV2

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1)
obj1.memberV1 = 1;
obj1.memberV2 = temp; //result from previous calculation
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1)
```

Comment: I think this could cause an update to be lost, if thread 1 executes your sample code and thread 2 updates `memberV1` in between thread 1 assigning `temp` and entering the mutex.

Comment: @finnw: The question itself suggests that this is a reader-writer scenario, so there should be no problem with the data changing when the writer doesn't expect it to.

Comment: Hard to say, without knowing more details. I think the real question is: does "some time consuming operation" require data from `obj1`? If so, then you probably cannot do it outside the lock.

Comment: @Anon, the new title suggests there are multiple writer threads.

Comment: @finnw: That title was edited in there by someone else, and appears to have been corrected now.

Comment: @finnw: if by "cause an update to be lost" you mean "memberV2 gets written multiple times before the reader thread sees it", nothing prevents that from happening even if you hold the mutex during the calculation. Multiple writer threads could run (or the same writer could run multiple times) before the reader gets scheduled.

Comment: @David Gelhar, I am assuming the value assigned to `memberV1` is also the input to the calculation.  I am also assuming that the reader thread accesses `memberV1` and `memberV2` only inside the mutex.  If these assumptions are correct then the reader thread will always see matching values (`memberV2` is the result of a computation based on `memberV1`.)

Comment: @finnw: Right, but to meet those requirements you don't need to do the computation inside the mutex (unless the computation itself refers to other members). You can do the computation without locking, then lock and assign the matching values to `memberV1` and `memberV2`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is separate the calculation from the update:

```
temp = some calculation
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
obj.memberV1 = 1;
obj.memberV2 = temp;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```